# Move strings to location

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm using NASM compiler to create small asm applications. I need to load my string on location and I want access it later. 
My question is: 
Is there any way to store strings in memory and load them later?
Somewhere I have ridden that it's possible with `offset` but I don't know how to use it in NASM. 
Can anybody place here links or code for explanation or example? Please help.

Comment: You write asm to produce machine code.  A processor doesn't know anything about strings.  You'll first have to define what a string looks like, then write the code to manipulate them.  Take a good look at how a C compiler does it.

Comment: as I tod. Compiler (VC) is using mov eax, offset string "string" but in NASM is impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike MASM and TASM, NASM does not use `offset`.

MASM/TASM code:

```
mov eax, offset MyString
MyString db "Hello World!", 10, 0
```

or

```
lea eax, MyString
MyString db "Hello World!", 10, 0
```

NASM equivalents:

```
mov eax, MyString
MyString db "Hello World!", 10, 0
```

or

```
lea eax, [MyString]
MyString db "Hello World!", 10, 0
```

Please read NASM documentation.

Comment: Section `2.2.2 NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References` describes the difference.